# Java IntelliJ What is the best way to analyse code for Null Pointer exceptions, Index out of bounds, etc

Tags: java, optimization, profiling

I am dealing with a legacy code base and am looking at ways to get instant feedback on the state of the code base. I have looked at options like Analyze > Inspect Code, etc. I was wondering if you guys can suggest some other options (I am after duplicates, code that can cause null pointer exceptions, index out of bounds, etc).

Also, wondering if anybody knows of option to run code with a profiler, which at the end of the run can provide me statistics of the problematic areas in the code post executions.

Comment: Have you tried the things [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/inferring-nullity.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recommend SonarLint Intellij plugin which also includes null pointer checks and a lot of other useful inspections. https://www.sonarlint.org/intellij/

Comment: Thanks Vadym, Sonarlint sounds like a really good option. I will give it a go and put my comments here on stackoverflow so that it is useful for others.